# Git clone error with beaglebone black

Tags: git, github, ssh, putty, beagleboneblack

I ssh to my beaglebone black via puTTy, I tried to download a source code from a github repository using the following steps below, but to no avail.
My git version is 1.7.7. I don't know if thats the problem, if it is, how can I get the latest version on my beagle bone.

1st attempt, cloning with ssh:

---

root@beaglebone:~# git clone git@github.com:o-botics/quickbot_bbb.git

Cloning into quickbot_bbb...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

---

2nd attempt, cloning with https:

---

root@beaglebone:~# git clone https://github.com/o-botics/quickbot_bbb.git

Cloning into quickbot_bbb...

error:  while accessing https://github.com/obotics/quickbot_bbb.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

---

PLease, a well detailed response will be most appreciated as I am a newbie at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub has been under a [constant DDoS attack](https://github.com/blog/1981-large-scale-ddos-attack-on-github-com) for nearly three days now.  This has been causing some difficulties for the site, and could be the root cause of your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir. I guess I just have to wait and try again after github fixes the problem.